# How to validate that "java -version" doesn't returns an error through the code?

Tags: java, install4j

In our organization, we supply an installer (Install4j) to build and run our product.

On one of the phases there we make a validation for the java version with `System.getProperty("java.version")`. In some rare cases, when typing `java -version` from the command prompt, it can gets a variety of errors, like:

[image]

The problem I facing is that these kind of errors are getting displayed only from the command prompt, while `System.getProperty("java.version")` won't alert any, just return the version number.

I'm looking for a way monitoring these kind of errors and stop the installer accordingly, but all my attempts were in vain.

**EDIT**:

I thought of getting use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, but nonetheless the *'java -version'* response won't come back.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a broken Java installation, you have to reinstall Java in that case.

Comment: Yes, I know. But my intention is to show a proper message to the client in such a case. I need to know when such error occurs in the installer.

Comment: That error would not occur in an installer in the same way. Do you bundle a JRE? Then this error does cannot occur. If not, the search sequence in the native executable generated by install4j will take care of finding a working JRE.

Comment: @ingoKegel - is there any way running the command **java -version** using 'Run executable or batch file' action?

Comment: Yes, you can do that and parse the output. Not sure how that would help you with the installer though, because if it is already running it will not have any problem with broken JRE installations.

Comment: @ingokegel - I understand what you are saying, nonetheless, a client of ours had this problem and the installer didn't alert any problem.
Can you guide me please how can I get the version and parse the output?

Comment: I have added an answer that shows the mechanics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a "Run executable or batch file" action, set the "Executable" property to

```
${installer:sys.javaHome}/bin/java.exe
```

the "Arguments" property to

```
-version
```

and the "Redirect stderr" property to "To installer variable" with the child property "Installer variable name" set to

```
javaVersionOutput
```

After the action has run, you can use a "Run script" property to inspect the output:

```
String output = context.getVariable("javaVersionOutput");
// TODO check output
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to handle the error and get the alert message:

```
String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");

if(!javaVersion.contains("1.7")) {
    System.out.println("jdk 1.7 is required.");
    System.out.println("Please install jdk 1.7");
}
```

Comment: This solution isn't good.
In the exampled error I included the version number does return, but there is still an error I miss...